# how to concat an observable properly

Tags: angular, rxjs

To start in my component i declare the observable...

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { tap, map, concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

contactsDataSource$: Observable<any>;
```

then I assign a stream to the observable from an http service:

```
this.contactsDataSource$ = this.medialistsrv.getMediaListBuilderData({
    mediaListId: this.mediaListId,
    sortType: this.sortType,
    startRow: this.startRow,
    numRows: this.numRows
}).pipe(
    tap(response => {
        this.mediaList = response
            .filter(items => items.inMediaList === true)
            .map(items => items.contactId);
        this.mediaList.forEach(id => {
            this._contacts.push(this.fb.control(id));
        });
    }),
    map(response => response)
);
```

and introduce it to the template with the async pipe:

```
<div *ngIf="(contactsDataSource$ | async) as contactList; else loading">
```

later in the template I introduce a method to load more results. this is where I need to concat to the initial stream

```
increment() {
    this.contactsDataSource$.concat(
        this.medialistsrv.getMediaListBuilderData({
            mediaListId: this.mediaListId,
            sortType: this.sortType,
            startRow: (this.numRows + 1),
            numRows: (this.numRows * 2)
        }).map(response => response)
    );
}
```

when running this I get an error in my console that says:

```
ng:///MediaListModule/MediaListBuilderComponent.ngfactory.js:351 ERROR TypeError: this.contactsDataSource$.concat is not a function
```

I am still on the rxjs learning cliff, so obviously I am not understanding how to do this correctly. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're mixing pipable and "prototype" operators. Use `this.contactsDataSource$.pipe(concat(...), map(...))`

Comment: this eliminated the error, but did not actually concat the new stream in the display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the way you're doing it is that the subscription will be finished after the first call to `getMediaListBuilderData`.  You need to setup the observable and how it concatenates the results from multiple sources before the first subscription.  Also if you want the actions in the pipe to occur with each result it needs to put after the concatenation of streams.

Create an observable from `concat` where you pass your initial call and a `Subject` that will passed to the subscribe methods of all invocations of `getMediaListBuilderData` in `increment()`.

```
this.incrementsSubject = new Subject<myType>();
this.contactsDataSource$ = 
    concat(
        this.medialistsrv.getMediaListBuilderData({
            mediaListId: this.mediaListId,
           sortType: this.sortType,
           startRow: this.startRow,
           numRows: this.numRows
        }
        , this.incrementsSubject)
    .pipe(
        tap(response => {
            this.mediaList = response
               .filter(items => items.inMediaList === true)
               .map(items => items.contactId);
            this.mediaList.forEach(id => this._contacts.push(this.fb.control(id)));
        }),
    );

increment() {

    this.medialistsrv
        .getMediaListBuilderData({
            mediaListId: this.mediaListId,
            sortType: this.sortType,
            startRow: (this.numRows + 1),
           numRows: (this.numRows * 2)
         })
         .subscribe(this.incrementsSubject);
}
```

Comment: Currently contactsDataSource$ is `contactsDataSource$: Observable<any>;`  So when I implement what you have above, I get `Type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.`

Comment: Change import to: `import { concat } from 'rxjs/observable/concat';`

Comment: Yes, you were on the right path here. What I ended up having to do was to create sort of a wrapper Observable and pipe/merge all of my other streams into it. Because each stream returns a mutated contacts array, it effectively cancels out the last. Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't quite understand what's going on.  I used to do wrapper observables when I started, but Subject is an observable and observer wrapper together and should negate the need for an Observable wrapper.  Happy to help either way.